# What does black box manner mean in Oblivious Transfer (OT)?

Tags: oblivious-transfer

I read a statement that states OT (Oblivious transfers) cannot be constructed from public key encryption in a black box manner.

What does it mean here by black box manner? Is Oblivious transfer a complete primitive?

Comment: Could you link your statement source into your question?

Answer (score 3):

In a black box manner means using a generic system in this case public key cryptography. Without dealing with internals or extra properties.
A public key encryption black box, has a public key and private key and you can encrypt with one and decrypt with the other and it is assumed you can not decrypt without the key.

A black box construction will work with any algorithm which matches this spec, the construction is valid regardless of which algorithm specifically is used, and only assumes the declared security properities.

We will try to prove, if we take a secure black box, we can with such and such construction create a new system with certain proveable security properties.

Because we don't know if cryptography works at all, maybe P=NP. So we like such constructions, it allows us to prove if A is secure so is B, so we are very specific about the security assumptions we make about our building blocks.

It also allows us to swap one building block for another, if I proved something based on a secure hash function and I used SHA-1 and it is no longer considered secure I replace with SHA-3 and the rest of the construction and the security proof still holds.